# PhoneStateListener is not working when inherited from another class

Tags: android, inheritance, phone-state-listener

I am trying to inherit a function from a class. It includes registering a PhoneStateListener.
The following is the function I try to inherit in Main.java.

```
    public Main(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
     registerPhoneStateListener();
     }

public void registerPhoneStateListener() {
 myPhoneStateListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
 telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 telephonyManager.listen(myPhoneStateListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
     }
```

myPhoneStateListener is a public class in the Main.java

```
    public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {...}
```

Here is the coding in my another class.

```
Main main =new Main(this);
main.registerPhoneStateListener();
```

The PhoneStateListener works fine in Main.java, but is not working in the another class.
Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's a difference. If you run the Activity then the SO setup the right things to make the Activity working propertly.
If you make the Activity using new it isnt the same thing.

Comment: do you mean it is impossible to inherit a PhoneStateListener from another class?

Comment: I think you should reconsider your class diagram if you really need to inherit from another class. I've never tried to start a listener from another class as you are doing but in my opinion when you instantiate an Activity by yourself it is very different.